# Adding a field in a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add a field in one of our query. I'm nt a PHP programmer buy I can get my way around a little. The query is:

```
if (_QUERYSTRING_) {
    switch ($intMode) {
        case -1:
            $result = mysqli_query($mysql,"
            SELECT   orders.id, 
                     orders_addresses.strlastname, 
                     orders_addresses.strfirstname, 
                     orders_addresses.intprovince, 
                     9 AS intmode, 
                     Date(orders.dtimeorder) AS datepayment, 
                     orders_costs.dbltotal AS dblamount, 
                     orders_notes.strcod AS strtxn, 
                     0 AS dblfee, 
                     shipping_postalservices.strtracking"._LANG_." as strtrackingurl, 
                     '&Agrave; recevoir' AS strmode, 
                     NULL AS strvendor 
            FROM     orders 
            JOIN     orders_costs 
            ON       orders_costs.id = orders.id 
            JOIN     orders_addresses 
            ON       orders_addresses.id = orders.id 
            JOIN     orders_notes 
            ON       orders_notes.id = orders.id 
            JOIN     shipping_postalservices 
            ON       shipping_postalservices.id = orders_costs.intpostalservice 
            WHERE    date(orders.dtimeorder) BETWEEN '".date("Y-m-d",$timeStart)."' AND      '".date("Y-m-d",$timeEnd)."' 
            AND      orders.boolshipped = 1 
            AND      orders.boolcanceled = 0 
            AND      orders_costs.boolcod = 1 
            AND      orders_costs.dbltotal > 0 
            AND      NOT EXISTS 
                     ( 
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM   orders_payments 
                        WHERE  orders_payments.intorder = orders.id 
                        AND    orders_payments.intmode = 9 
                        AND    orders_payments.dblamount > 0) 
        GROUP BY orders.id 
        ORDER BY orders.dtimeorder, 
                 orders.id");
            break;
        default:
            $result = mysqli_query($mysql,"
            SELECT    orders.id, 
                      orders_addresses.strlastname, 
                      orders_addresses.strfirstname, 
                      orders_addresses.intprovince, 
                      orders_payments.intmode, 
                      Date(orders_payments.dtimepayment) AS datepayment, 
                      orders_payments.dblamount, 
                      orders_payments.strtxn, 
                      orders_payments.dblfee, 
                      shipping_postalservices.strtracking"._LANG_." as strtrackingurl, 
                      payments.strname"._LANG_." AS strmode, 
                      payments.strvendor 
            FROM      orders_payments 
            JOIN      orders 
            ON        orders.id = orders_payments.intorder 
            JOIN      orders_costs 
            ON        orders_costs.id = orders.id 
            JOIN      orders_addresses 
            ON        orders_addresses.id = orders.id 
            JOIN      shipping_postalservices 
            ON        shipping_postalservices.id = orders_costs.intpostalservice 
            LEFT JOIN payments 
            ON        payments.id = orders_payments.intmode 
            WHERE     date(orders_payments.dtimepayment) BETWEEN '".date("Y-m-d",$timeStart)."' AND       '".date("Y-m-d",$timeEnd)."'".(!empty($intMode) ? " 
            AND       orders_payments.intmode = '".$intMode."'" : NULL)." 
            GROUP BY  orders.id, 
                      orders_payments.intpayment 
            ORDER BY  orders_payments.dtimepayment, 
                      orders.id");
            break;
    }
```

The field that needs to be added is `orders_addresses.intProvince` so it can be displayed in the results. I tried to understand a little but I guess it's a little more complicated than I thought. It does display the province, which are numbers. My question would be, how do I "translate" those numbers by the actual names so it displays "Ontario" instead of 9? The name of the provinces are in another table called `Province`.

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: Agree with @Mike - just add it (,orders_addresses.intProvince as Something) - at the end of the current SELECT list and before the FROM.

Comment: Try formatting your query instead of using one single line 1000 characters long

Comment: Sorry guys, posted my comment before finishing :S

Comment: To translate the province number to a name, you need to join with the `Province` table. If you don't know how to do a join, you need to read a SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add another JOIN:

```
JOIN Province ON orders_addresses.intprovince = Province.x
```

And in the SELECT part, replace `orders_addresses.intprovince` by `Province.y`

where

x = column in table Province that holds the province id
y = column in table Province that holds the province name